# How can I implement two tax rates on a single method?

Tags: java

So I am very new to java and am confused about the `getTax()` method.

```
public class General extends Customer {

    private double taxRateTickets = .06;
    private double taxRateService = .04;

    public General(String customerCode, String type, Person contact, String name,
        Address address) {
        super(customerCode, type, contact, name, address);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public double getTax() {
        return      
    }

    abstract public double discount();
    abstract public double additionalFee();
}
```

Basically I have to make an invoice report in another class and I need to get the tax rate for a general(subclass) customer(superclass). If I have two different products with different tax rates, how can I return a tax for them in the `getTax()` method?

Comment: are your products other objects? Or do you mean a general object and a customer object with the "two different products"?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like class homework so I will just push you in the right direction: Have a look at overloading a method in Java and you will know what to do.
You will end up with two methods both being named getTaxes but depending on the type of the argument the correct method is chosen by java.

Also there is a much dirtier solution: You could make only one getTaxes method and use `instanceof`  to check the type of the methods argument. But I strongly recommend to not do it this way!

Comment: Or use a design pattern like strategy https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy

Comment: So could my arguments be getTaxes(double price, double rate) ?